# Could not load library libcublasLt.so.10

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

On a machine that has Tensorflow 2.11, CUDA 11.3, CUDNN 8.4, python 3.8, running elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki which is based on Ubuntu 16.04.2, I am keep getting the error "Error: libcublasLt.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" when trying to run a python file. After running `nvcc -V` and `nvidia-smi`, this is the result:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II9zE.jpg)

I have tried downloading CUDA Toolkit 10.2 (Nov 2019), Versioned Online Documentation, but I dont think it downloaded correctly or if thats even the correct way of going about this.

Answer (score 0):

Are the CUDA libraries in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

For the default install location this should work:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:\usr\local\cuda\lib64
```

If you have multiple CUDA installations you may need to make sure you point to the right one:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:\usr\local\cuda-11.3\lib64
```